# Spanner row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY.. ORDER BY)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

How do we write the following in Google Spanner, for some analytical function. If this is not possible any other alternate way to write the below SQL

```
row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY c1,c2 ORDER BY c3 DESC )
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `c3` is unique, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c2 = t.c1 and t2.c3 >= t.c3
       ) 
from t;
```

This is usually much less efficient than window functions, but is a possibility in databases that do not support them.